# Letter is gone from attribute field name after saving edits

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

This field name loses the letter A after I save edits.
`Link to SOA`

Before save.
[image]

After save and edits applied.
[image]

However, the edits are saved if I take out the white spaces.
[image]

Comment: It's a shapefile correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are working with a shapefile which has field name limited to 10 characters. You can refer to this [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00126-00150-000142.htm#:%7E:text=Field%20names%20for%20shapefiles%20and,than%2010%20characters%20in%20length.) from Esri which clearly identified this limitation. You need to shorten the name to be less than or equal 10 characters, if you want to continue to use shapefiles, or use another vector format such as geopackage if you want to create field name more than 10 characters.

Comment: This is a shapefile. I originally exported it from ArcGIS Pro. Then I added it to my QGIS project. I also shortened the field to ```SOA Link``` in the table and the edits were applied. Thanks!